# how to make matlab display decimal number?

Tags: matlab

I want to run harmoney search algorithm in matlab, and my data set is the number of feature saved in excel with 11 column, I read my file from excel with this command `A=xlsread(filename);` in matlab, and my file has the value of 0 1 and decimal number, but when I run my program I get NaN instead of decimal number in the out put. so I get NaN value for my best cost, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you've not given us enough information to help. You need to give us enough details that we can recreate the problem. Show us the contents of the excel file (or make a small test example), i.e. the input, show us the code you called and show us the exact output you received, Then explain what's wrong (if it's not obvious).
My guess is you have text in your Excel file (not just numbers).

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Remember that we can’t look on your computer screen to see what you did, you have to show us!